# Qt internal threads

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have Qt application, with some external library dependencies. My application and external libraries does not use threads (seems to me). There is no `thread` word in sources of them. One library have derivative from `QTcpServer` with *no* `listen()` method overloading. (OS is windows)

I create an object and call `listen()` method in the constructor of `Window` class. The warning message at console appears during `listen()` method call:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different
>   thread. (Parent is QJsonRpcTcpServer(0x4c1b38), parent's thread is
>   QThread(0x4a8d98), current thread is QThread(0x47e348)

The Qt subsystem and so on create additional threads, one of them UI thread etc. Some mesh or intersection exists or something else. After that program is not worked properly. (tcp client `connect` and lies until program is not closed)

What is the possible vector to debug problem?

```
Window::Window( QWidget *parent ) { 
    Service* service = new Service( parent );
    QJsonRpcTcpServer* rpcServer = new QJsonRpcTcpServer( parent );
    rpcServer->addService(service);
    // problem at next line:
    if ( rpcServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 42123) ) {
    }
}
```

Some new info, when I replace QJsonRpcTcpServer with QTcpServer then warning at `listen()` call is disappear.

Some more new info, the problem is on windows. Build and run at FreeBSD is ok - no errors and work as expected.

Comment: Run your application in a debugger and add a breakpoint on the spawn of new threads; the exact method depends from which debugger you use.

Comment: Just don't set parents to Sevice and QJsonRpcTcpServer. Use `connect( parent, &QObject::destroyed, obj, &QObject::deleteLater );` call to release memory

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, that signal is useful but hardly for all cases starting with simple plain C++ object not derived from QObject, etc.

Comment: It is OK to be a child of `QObject`. I'm talking just about settings parent objects.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I was happy for this answer and have think that it solve problem. But no, it is not. Seems it is library bug or configuration wrong. I think that your answer is useful for such cases. Make it as answer, I'll vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I deal with the debug message and the fact that the worker thread prevented to start? I am getting:
>   "Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread." message in debug output.

There several ways to dynamically allocate the object and still keep track of it in Qt without using `QObject` base with parent (owner) passed to it. For example `QScopedPointer` as a member of a class of that 'parent' object instead:

```
/// snip ///
#include <QScopedPointer>
class Service;
class QJsonRpcTcpServer;

class Window : public QWidget
{
   /// snip ///
   QScopedPointer<Service> m_service;
   QScopedPointer<QJsonRpcTcpServer> m_rpcServer;
};

/// snip ///

Window::Window( QWidget *parent ) { 
    m_service.reset(new Service( nullptr ));             // unsure of default 
    m_rpcServer.reset(new QJsonRpcTcpServer( nullptr )); // constructor, take nullptr
    m_rpcServer->addService(m_service);
    // was problem at next line: not anymore
    if ( m_rpcServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 42123) ) {
    }
}
```

I also suspect that `QJsonRpcTcpServer::addService` is taking responsibility of releasing 'service' object. But that I cannot prove with docs, so try to find an answer to it as well. Mind that `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr` will always work deterministic but `QObject::destroyed` signal doing deferred release via `QObject::deletelater` is more prone to 'surprises' starting from when exactly the object gets released.